# How to override behaviour for IME_ACTION_PREVIOUS in ReactTextInputManager?

Tags: react-native, android-tv, react-native-tvos

Taking a look at [this line](https://github.com/react-native-tvos/react-native-tvos/blob/tvos-v0.72.4/packages/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputManager.java#L1117) it seems like all of actions in IME_MASK_ACTION trigger the submit event. I'd like to override this behaviour to make the IME_ACTION_PREVIOUS action work as a "back" button and dismiss the keyboard.

Does anybody know if this is possible? I managed to get my desired behaviour by directly modifying the file inside node_modules, but would like any way to override it from my project. I'm considering [patching](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) the package, but not sure if this is the best way.

Working on react-native-tvos@0.72.6-0